# how to get into the selected activity in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, intentfilter

MainActivitty.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      // list view
      private ListView lv;

      // listview adapter
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

      // search edittext
      EditText inputsearch;

      // arraylist for listview
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> negaralist;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // data array yang akan ditampilkan di list 
    String negara[] = {"indonesia","malaysia","brunei","filipina",
              "thailand","myanmar","singapura","vietnam",
              "kamboja","laos","brazil","amerika","inggris","italia","france","kamerun",
              "argentina","portugal","germany","spanyol","mexico","kanada","belgium"};
    // ambil list_view dan inputsearchnya di xml 
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // proses menambahkan array kedalam listview 
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_filter,
        R.id.negara_name, negara);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * kode dibawah ini dipakai untuk memfilter/pencarian realtime 
     * */
    inputsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);


    }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});

    lv.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3){
            Intent i = null;
            if (position == 0){
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Indonesia.class);}
            else if(position == 1){
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Malaysia.class);}
else if(position == 2){
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Brunei.class);}
else if(position == 3){
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Filipina.class);}
else if(position == 4){
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Thailand.class);}
else if(position == 5){
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Myanmar.class);}
else if(position == 6){
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Singapur.class);}
else if(position == 7){
                i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Vietnam.class);}
        startActivity(i);

        }
        });}
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
            }

    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search Country.."
        />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</Linear
```

lis_item_filter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >     

    <TextView android:id="@+id/negara_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

when I was looking for a country with the keyword "i" which came out Indonesia, inggris and italia. when I select Indonesia,  entry into indonesia activity, but when I select inggris why the entry into malaysia activity.
how to get into the selected activity? what are there wrong on click listener?help me

Comment: there is no English in the list

Comment: @r7v You mean England? Also, iyyan71, you should be more clear when asking questions. Please show you have made an effort to research to solve your problems, and avoid simply pasting code for us to sort out.

Comment: sorry, I mean inggris, beginning with the letter "i" not english. please help me, how to get into the activities of which select. what are there wrong on clicklistener?

Answer (score 0):

'position' is from the lv object, thus your filtered list, not your original string list. Therefore when you select "inggris", the retruned position is 1 and starts malaysia activity. Please try:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3){
LinearLayout tmpll = (LinearLayout) view;
TextView tmptv = (TextView) tmpll.findViewById(R.id.negara_name);
pos = negara.indexOf(tmptv.getText());
```

and changes other "position" to "pos".